# running Firebase Cloud messaging onMessageReceived when sleep or in background without user action

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase cloud messaging in my app to execute code in the overridden onMessageReceived function. IT works fine when the app is in the foreground but not when idle/sleep or in background. I do receive the message in the notification tray but the code doesn't run. I know an action could be set up to run the code when a user clicks the notification in the trey but I want it to run without any user interaction. Is there a way to get this to run or is there a better solution that FCM.

The end goal is to ping the device from a server (done now through the FCM token) and then immediately have the device upload the devices location. Is there a better way?

Here is my FCM code.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class FMS extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public FMS() {
    }

    public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "Remote_Execute";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {



        Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_FILTER);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to send a `data`-*only* message payload. See [Handling Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) documentation.

Comment: Got it working with data only thanks. Found out I can't send a data only test in the the firebase console so I have to write some PHP cURL code to get this done. Messages are coming through fine in both open and sleep state. Weird behavior though, everything works normal when app is open but when app is closed some functions of the app shut down and if sending 2 messages in a row before opening app the app freezes some times. I don't see any errors posting in logcat though. I'm guessing I'm not handling the message in the onMessageReceived function. Looking into it. ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

see the difference between `data messages` and `notification messages` in the firebase cloud messaging documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages